# Which of these functions is the most proper in terms style and cleanliness?

Tags: coding-style

I'm having an internal dispute about the right way to do something.  Maybe you can help :)

Let's say I have the functions

```
foo(x, y) 
{  
  if (x satisfies condition c1)
    if (y satisfies condition c2)
      bar(x)
  else
    bar(x)

  ...
}

bar(x)
{
  ...
}
```

An alternative to this would be

```
foo(x, y) 
{ 
  doBarFlag = false
  if (x satisfies condition c1)
    if (y satisfies condition c2)
      doBarFlag = true
  else
    doBarFlag = true

  if (doBarFlag)
  {
    ...code from bar() goes in here
  }

  ...
}
```

And another alternative (slight variation of above)

```
foo(x, y) 
{ 
  doBarFlag = true
  if (x satisfies condition c1)
    if (y DOES NOT satisfy condition c2)
      doBarFlag = false

  if (doBarFlag)
  {
    ...code from bar() goes in here
  }

  ...
}
```

Assume that bar() is less than ten lines.  Which style would you prefer?  Why?  I'm leaning toward the first example, but I'd like to know what others think.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for properly wording and formatting your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
foo( x, y ) {
  if ( ! c1(x) || c2(y) )
    bar(x)
}
```

There's a name for this logic transformation, which I forget…

Comment: @Amber: nope, those relate to transforming AND to OR. What I did here is combine `(c1 && c2) || !c1` into `c2 || !c1`. You can get there by applying De Morgan a few times and getting rid of redundancies, but there's a name for doing it in one step.

Comment: Potatoswatter, thanks for this.  If you come across the name for the transmation, I'd love to know.

Comment: @Potato: Boolean algebra: `~P + PQ = (~P + P)(~P + Q)` by distributivity, then `(~P + P)` is a tautology. So the whole thing is `(~P + Q)`

Comment: Following your lead, in propositional logic:

bar() is called when `!p` or `(p ^ q)`.  So
`!p v (p ^ q) => (!p v p) ^ (!p v q) [distributivity] => T ^ (!p v q) => (!p v q)`

Next time I get stuck on something like this, I'll have to go back to my roots!

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `!a || b` is `a => b`, and `a => b` is equivalent to `a => a && b`, which is `(a && b) || !a`, what you wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have good suggestions on how to improve the code, I just have a styling suggestion. I would have braces on all code blocks regardless of length:

```
// C# style
foo(x, y) 
{ 
    if (condition) 
    {
        // do something
    }
    else 
    {
        // do something else
    }
}

// What I normally use
foo(x, y) { 
    if (condition) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

That way if you want to add another statement later it won't be added in the wrong place.
But don't get too religious on styling, just be consistent with whatever you use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, one of the reasons for defining functions is to be able to refer to (and not have to repeat) a bunch of code, using a short name. Hence, using that short name repeatedly isn't necessarily a bad thing. Thus, your option #1 is perfectly reasonable, and the least redundant.

Second of all, if that's really all that's going on in foo(), why not just do this instead?

```
foo(x, y) 
{  
  if (x satisfies condition c1) && !(y satisfies condition c2)
    return

  bar(x)
}
```

or even just

```
foo(x, y) 
{  
  if !(x satisfies condition c1) || (y satisfies condition c2)
    bar(x) 
}
```

In most languages, the && and || operators (or their equivalents) are *short-circuited*, and thus won't try to evaluate their right-hand side if they can determine their truth value from just the left. As such, you often don't need to worry about things like "property compared in y only exists if x is true" or the like.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the fact that foo() does do more than what I had originally mentioned, so returning isn't the way to go.  But your second suggestion is exactly what I needed.  I got stuck in a box thinking about the logic there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
foo(x,y)
{
    if(x satisfies c1 && y does not satisfy c2)
        return;
    bar(x);
}
```

this way you can easily see that when bar(x) is not executed.